# many definions in let - why error

Tags: haskell

look at it:

```
e >>= f = StOut (\n ->  let     (a, n1, s1) = (unStOut e) n
                                (b, n2, s2) = (unStOut (f a)) n1
                        in      (b, n2, s1++s2))
```

The ghci complains about:  `parse error on input ‘=’`
However, for

```
e >>= f = StOut (\n ->  let     (a, n1, s1) = (unStOut e) n
                            in  (a, n1, s1))
```

ghci likes it :)
Where is the error ?

Comment: It is not a syntax error for me. Which version of GHC are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably not in that code snippet: lambdabot accepts `@letlpaste 4789689228613124096` just fine (which loads http://lpaste.net/4789689228613124096 into its ghci). Try pasting the entire code file that leads to this error.